# DataTables Plugin When Click Editing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have question . I am using datatables plugin with update panel. I want to do When I click Update selected rows updating. But When I have one more pages I have problem. Because When I click 2. Pages click update return 1 pages. I want to do stay this page. What can I do.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlicerik" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="example" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="gvdatatable" OnRowDataBound="example_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="example_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="example_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="example_RowUpdating" ClientIDMode="Static">

                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Sıra" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <%--  <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtad" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Başlık" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblGonderino" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BaslikAd") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbaslikad" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BaslikAd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tarih" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblgonderen" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tarih") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <%-- <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txttarih" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tarih") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seo" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblalici" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Seo") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <%--   <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtseo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Seo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Onaylı" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblagirlik" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ok") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <%--  <asp:TextBox ID="txtok" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ok") %>'></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chck" runat="server" />

                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kullanıcı" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblvaris" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <%--  <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtuserid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Servis" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblservis" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AdminID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtadminid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AdminID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>




                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific.  Your question is confusing and needs more clarification about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you see picture. İf I 2. Pages When I click Düzenle(Edit) button. After turn 1.pages. I want to do stay that page.

Comment: I'm confused too, it doesn't look like your code corresponds to your table. Maybe provide the HTML after it's been evaluated?

Comment: I explained frankly. But do you want understand. I can show on ammyy.

Comment: After update use page function https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to mix GridView, UpdatePanel and Datatables in my experience. The updated GridView probably triggers the Datatable script to redraw.

You could try and fire `table.page(2)` after an update, but I would suggest that you fetch your data and update your table through an Ajax request and redraw or update your data source for the table. Of course you wouldn't have the editing templates out of the box.